# Counting the number of "on" bits in an int

Tags: c, integer, bitwise

Here is some code I wrote as a solution to Programming Exercise 15.3 in Stephen Prata's *C Primer Plus, 6th Edition*. It is probably worth pointing out that the title of the chapter is **Bit Fiddling**. The question asks:

> Write a function that takes an **int** argument and returns the number
>   of "on" bits in the argument. Test the function in a program.

My code seems to work for a variety of test-cases. But bit-fiddling seems finicky, and I was wondering if anyone could see any mistakes here. I would also be very interested to hear about ways to improve this code, or better approaches (e. g., more concise, or more efficient) to the problem.

The code that I have forms a bitmask from an `unsigned int` with only the bit corresponding to the sign bit of the input `int` set to "on", and then proceeds to check the bits of the input `int` against the bitmask, moving the test bit towards the lower order bits at each iteration until the last bit has been tested.

Since first posting this question, I have begun to feel uneasy about the expression:

```
(b_mask & num)
```

as `b_mask` is an `unsigned int` and `num` is an `int`. It usually seems like a bad idea to mix signed and unsigned types in the same expression. Is the result of this operation reliable? Any thoughts on this particular issue would be welcome.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int on_bits(int num);

int main(void)
{
    int input;

    printf("Enter an int value ('q' to quit): ");
    while (scanf("%d", &input) == 1) {
        printf("%d\n", on_bits(input));
        printf("Enter an int value ('q' to quit): ");
    }

    return 0;
}

int on_bits(int num)
{
    int res = 0;
    unsigned b_mask = 0x1;

    /* Move to sign bit */
    for (int i = 1; i < (sizeof(num) * CHAR_BIT); i++)
        b_mask <<= 1;

    /* Check bits */
    while (b_mask > 0) {
        if (b_mask & num)
            ++res;
        b_mask >>= 1;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Here is a sample interaction:

> ```
> Enter an int value ('q' to quit): 255
> 8
> Enter an int value ('q' to quit): -255
> 25
> Enter an int value ('q' to quit): 2048
> 1
> Enter an int value ('q' to quit): 2047    
> 11
> Enter an int value ('q' to quit): -2047
> 22
> Enter an int value ('q' to quit): 4095
> 12
> Enter an int value ('q' to quit): -4095
> 21
> Enter an int value ('q' to quit): -1234567
> 22
> Enter an int value ('q' to quit): -987654321
> 16
> Enter an int value ('q' to quit): q
> ```

Comment: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive

Comment: Thanks for the very interesting link. The naive approach that you linked to will not work for negative values, which I took to be important in the solution of this problem. But, there was another method attributed to Kernighan there that was very interesting. I have added my own answer below to discuss this possibility. Thanks again!

Comment: Try not to adapt your question post to answers being posted.

Comment: I added back that particular part, with the reference to your answer removed

Comment: @DavidBowling it works regardless of signness. Just change the type to what you need. However it's quite slow and is often only used for demonstration. [How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/109023/995714)

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc-- I actually tried exactly this code with `int` instead of `unsigned int` on my system, and it failed. According to the C99 standard (6.5.7/5) the result of a right bit-shift of a negative value is implementation defined. [My answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/146180/counting-the-number-of-on-bits-in-an-int/146324#146324) below discusses another method from your link that is similarly simple, but very interesting, a little bit more efficient, and adaptable to negative values.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### The current implementation

Your implementation is correct, and takes \$O(n)\$ time, where \$n\$ is the number of bits in an `int`.  One thing you can improve is the initial setting of `b_mask`.  Currently, you use a loop, but it can be done like this:

```
unsigned int b_mask = 1u << (sizeof(b_mask)*CHAR_BIT - 1);
```

Actually, there are two other strategies you can use as well:

1. Start `b_mask` at 1 and left shift it instead of right shift it.
2. Get rid of `b_mask` and shift the number instead.

For an example of #2:

```
int on_bits(unsigned int num)
{
    int res = 0;

    while (num != 0) {
        res += (num & 0x1);
        num >>= 1;
    }

    return res;
}
```

#### Other implementations

There are a wide variety of ways to count bits.  You should read [the wikipedia page on Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) for starters.  I'll briefly mention some here:

**Removing one bit per loop**

There is a bit trick that removes the lowest set bit.  So instead of looping \$n\$ times (e.g. 32), you can only loop \$m\$ times, where \$m\$ is the number of bits actually set. So if there is only 1 bit set, you only have to loop once.  The code looks like this:

```
int on_bits(unsigned int num)
{
    int res = 0;

    while (num != 0) {
        num &= num - 1;
        res++;
    }

    return res;
}
```

**Using hardware instruction**

Many CPUs have a dedicated instruction for counting bits (e.g. `popcnt` for X86).  Your compiler probably has a way of accessing this instruction (e.g. `__builtin_popcount()` for GNU.  This will be the fastest of all implementations but will be hardware and compiler dependent.

```
int on_bits(unsigned int num)
{
    return __builtin_popcount(num);
}
```

**Using a lookup table**

Suppose you created a lookup table with 256 entries that contained the number of bits set in each byte value 0..255.  Then your code would need to loop only 4 times instead of 32:

```
static const uint8_t bitsInByte[256] = { /* Prefilled in */ };
int on_bits(unsigned int num)
{
    int res = 0;

    while (num != 0) {
        res += bitsInByte[num & 0xff];
        num >>= 8;
    }

    return res;
}
```

**Using parallelism and bit tricks**

This is described in the wikipedia article in depth.  Here I give the 32-bit version instead of the 64-bit one:

```
// Assumes int is 32 bits
int on_bits(unsigned int num)
{
    num -= ((num >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    num  = (num & 0x33333333) + ((num >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    return (((num + (num >> 4)) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24;
}
```

#### One's complement

According to later comments by the OP, being able to handle one's complement is important, and the input argument should be `int` instead of `unsigned int`.  You can still use all of the functions above, if you first prepare the input argument by stripping its sign bit, like this:

```
int on_bits(int num)
{
    int signBit = 1 << (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT - 1);
    int res     = (num & signBit) != 0;

    num &= ~signBit;

    // Now, num has its sign bit stripped so it can be right shifted.
    // Res is 1 if the sign bit was set, or 0 if it was not.

    // Do the rest here...
}
```

Comment: @JS1-- This is exactly what I was looking for. I can't believe that I missed the obvious and set `b_mask` in a loop instead of using a single bit-shifting operation! Thank you for all of the information.

Comment: Gotta love bit fiddling on a Friday night. A most interesting read.

Comment: @JS1-- I was just looking over your answer again, and it occurs to me that many of the possibilities that you mention may not work for this particular problem, as the input is an `int`, not an `unsigned int`. This could lead to problems, at least for the solutions involving right-shifts of the bits of the input number. Still, your answer was very informative and has given me plenty to think about.

Comment: @DavidBowling If the input must be signed, then Just cast the input argument to an unsigned int.  Like this: `int on_bits(int n) { unsigned int num = (unsigned int) n; ... `

Answer (score 3):

You can improve the performance of the routine by using more memory. The way to do it is that instead of considering 1 single bit at a time and checking if it's on or not, consider multiple bits at a time, say 4. We then can build a table of every possible arrangements of 4 bits (2^4 = 16 entries) and store the number of enabled bits in it.

Then for any number, we can mask off 4 bits at a time, look it up in the table, and add that to the running total before shifting over by 4 bits. This approach can be extended to any number of bits, but for each additional bit, you would use twice as much memory to hold the table.

Answer (score 0):

I received some excellent answers and comments on this question. If I didn't make it clear when I asked, the problem states that the function should take an `int` argument, and I took this literally to mean that the value may be negative, and that the function should count the sign bit as well as the value bits.

Many potential solutions require bit-shifting the input number to the right, and this of course causes problems for negative values. It was suggested that casting the input `int` to `unsigned int` would solve this issue. It is true that the bit pattern is preserved under such a cast if the underlying representation is two's complement, but the standard explicitly allows for one's complement and sign-magnitude representations as well. The bit pattern is not preserved under this casting in these alternative representations.

@Lưu Vĩnh Phúc provided a very informative link that had one solution that intrigued me, so I will write about it here.

The [method](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetKernighan) comes from Kernighan, but apparently was first published by Peter Wegner. The idea is to remove the least significant bit by doing a bitwise `&` with the result of subtracting 1 from the number. The nice thing about this method is that it iterates not once for each bit in the input number, but only once for each significant bit.

The code at the link takes an `unsigned int` for input, but I have adapted the code to work for `int` inputs. My version uses a bit mask to control the loop, checking to see if the input number can be further reduced. Since the sign bit cannot be removed by subtraction, it is counted at loop initialization:

```
int on_bits(int num)
{
    int c;                   // c accumulates the total bits set in num
    int sb;                  // used to mask sign bit

    sb = ~(0x1 << (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) - 1));
    for (c = (num < 0 ? 1 : 0); num & sb; c++) {
        num &= num - 1;      // clear the least significant bit set
    }

    return c;
}
```

I believe that this code works for both one's and two's complement representations, but it fails for sign-magnitude representations.

By way of explanation, for positive values, subtracting 1 flips the least significant bit:

```
...1100 - 1 --> ...1011
```

The least significant bit can be removed from a number by doing a bitwise `&` on the result of this subtraction:

```
...1100 & (...1100 - 1) --> ...1100 & ...1011 --> ...1000
```

For negative values, in two's complement, subtracting 1 gives:

```
...1100 - 1 --> -(2^N - ...1100) - 1 --> -(2^N - ...1100 + 1)
            --> -(2^N - (...1100 - 1)) --> -(2^N - ...1011)
            --> ...1011
```

That is, subtraction of 1 from the two's complement representation of a negative number yields a negative number with value bits that are the result of subtracting one from the original value bits. So, again, we can remove the least significant bit with:

```
...1100 & (...1100 - 1) --> ...1100 & ...1011 --> ...1000
```

For negative values in one's complement, subtracting 1 gives:

```
...1100 - 1 --> -(-...1100 + 1) --> ~(~...1100 + 1)
            --> ~(...0011 + 1) --> ~...0100 --> ...1011
```

That is, subtracting 1 from the one's complement representation of a negative number flips the least significant bit. This again allows the same removal strategy.

But, this method does not work for negative values in sign-magnitude representation. Here, subtracting 1 gives:

```
1...1100 - 1 --> -(0...1100 + 1) --> -0...1101 --> 1...1101
```

Comment: By definition, **any** function that counts set bits will be implementation specific because the implementation details of the `int` type are implementation specific.

Comment: @Edward-- I am not sure that I get your meaning. If you are saying that an implementation that uses two's complement will produce different results than one that uses one's complement, then yes, of course. But it would be nice if the same code worked on both implementations. The solution in my original question works for all three of the representations allowed by the standard. The solution in this answer works for two of the three representations. The bit-counts will differ, but the code will still work.

Comment: @Edward-- that said, I have reservations about my use of both **unsigned** and **int** in the same expression in my original code, and the effects of padding bits in this situation are unclear to me, as I don't have a good handle on exactly how padding bits work in integer representations.

Comment: To the latter point, this proposed code has a similar issue because both `CHAR_BIT` and the result of the `sizeof` operator could either be signed or unsigned.  This is a good illustration of the previous point which is that the same code might "work" on different implementations or it might not.  It also might produce the same number given the same input, or it might not.  This is the very definition of non-portable code, but the fault is not in your implementation -- it's inherent to the problem.

Comment: @Edward-- Thank you for your observations. This is exactly why I put this here. I was under the impression that the *additive-expression* of a bitwise shift operator was only required to be non-negative, which the above expression satisfies. I don't see how this is a problem here. What am I missing?

Comment: The standard says, of the left bitshift operator, that "If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined."  The *additive-expression* `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) - 1`does not *necessarily* assure that because both `CHAR_BIT` and `sizeof(int)` (and for that matter, `- 1`) are all implementation defined.

Comment: It's exceedingly likely that everything will work out (e.g. no numeric overflow from the multiplication) and that every real implementation uses two's-complement, but I don't believe it's guaranteed by my reading of the standard.  If I had more time to look into it, I'd provide an alternative answer.  Perhaps I will if I get some time this week.

Comment: @Edward-- the standard guarantees 2's, 1's, or sign-magnitude representation (c99 6.2.6.2/2). For this solution, I only claim that it will work for both 2's and 1's complement. (6.5.3.4/4) guarantees that the result of **sizeof** is an unsigned integer type. If I am reading (5.2.4.2/1) correctly, **CHAR_BIT** must be positive and at least **8**, so this expression must be non-negative. If I am missing something here, I really want to understand it. I would also love to see an alternative, if you get a chance. Thank you for the attention.

Comment: Maybe I should change to: `int sb = 0x1; sb <<= (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) - 1); sb = ~sb;`? Do I need to do this to guarantee that 0x1 can always be bit-shifted by the required amount?

Comment: This is not the naive way. The naive way works with any signed format, regardless of logical or arithmetic shift because the final result is always **and** with 1. This way implies 2's complement

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc -- I don't claim that this is the naive way. This is based on Kernighan's method from your link. This way works for 2's complement, and I believe also for 1's complement. But [this naive method](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive) failed on my system, for negative values of `v`, due to bit-shifting a negative value to the right. The loop never terminates, I believe because `v` never reaches 0.

Comment: Then you can simply shift to the left. Anyway the recommended solution is using a table lookup or parallel counting. Those are much faster than this simple way